# confused about nhibernate n+1 alert message

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, orm

In my query there I'm trying to select all entities (20 of them) and iterate through collection like this

```
List<Domain.Property> data = session.Query<Domain.Property>().ToList();

PropertyViewModel viewModel;
List<PropertyViewModel> listOfViewModels = new List<PropertyViewModel>();

foreach (Domain.Property prop in data)
{
    viewModel = new PropertyViewModel()
    {
        AdType = prop.AdType.ToString(), 
        CityName = prop.CityName, 
        ContructionYear = prop.ConstructionYear, 
        Photo = prop.Photos.First()

    };
}
listOfViewModels.Add(viewModel);
```

Each property MUST have one or more photos, I need only first one so I'm using Photos.First()

When this line is commented out Photo = prop.Photos.First() nhib. profiler reports that 20 entities is loaded which is fine (those from first query).

But with Photo = prop.Photos.First() loaded entities increased to 65 entities that number should approx. equal to properties + photos collections.

Can anyone point to right direction ?

And in nhib. generated sql there is

```
SELECT photos0_.PropertyId    as PropertyId1_,
       photos0_.Id            as Id1_,
       photos0_.Id            as Id1_0_,
       photos0_.ImageData     as ImageData1_0_,
       photos0_.ImageMimeType as ImageMim3_1_0_,
       photos0_.PropertyId    as PropertyId1_0_
FROM   Photo photos0_
WHERE  photos0_.PropertyId = 117 /* @p0 */
```

**which is marked as SELECT N+1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each property (single query to get the list of them) you're doing another query to get the first photo.  The `Photos` collection isn't populated until you try to access it resulting in a second query.

Join to the photos table as part of the original query to reduce it to a single query.

Comment: Or set a non-zero batch size in the mappings of the photo collection to make NHibernate initialize the collection for multiple owners at a time.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins but If I'm using in first query List<Domain.Property> data = session.Query<Domain.Property>().Fetch(x=>x.Photos).ToList(); I will fetch all collection, I need only first

Comment: Does the first photo have any special meaning for you? The way you are loading the first photo now will select the first photo by using the SQL server's natural sort order, which may not be what you need in the long run anyways.

Comment: I do need only first photo, cause that's what I'm using in that viewModel, nowhere else to reduce loading time.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins can you show example of joining photos object

Comment: @panjo, I'm not convinced that you current method of loading photos only load the first for each property. It should initialize the collection with all elements, then grab the first one.